# In Postgresql, can you express and check a constraint without adding it to an entity?

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, unique-constraint

What I'm looking for is behavior like what you would observe when adding a constraint (e.g., unique) to an existing table, validating it against the existing data, then removing the constraint. I don't want the constraint to persist on the table, I just want to express it, validate it on existing data, then move on (or raise an exception of the check fails); **Does Postgresql (9.2) support a way to do this sort of thing directly?**

Comment: You could use a `select` statement counting the rows that would violate the "condition". e.g. for a unique constraint that would involve a `group by` and `having count(*) > 1`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks for the suggestion. How could I then do something, e.g., throw an exception, if the constraint is violated (top-level branching, i.e., CASE..., is syntactically invalid)? Would this require using a procedural language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the constraint:

```
alter table t
add constraint the_pk primary key (user_id);
NOTICE:  ALTER TABLE / ADD PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "the_pk" for table "t"
ERROR:  could not create unique index "the_pk"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(1) is duplicated.
```

If there was no error drop it:

```
alter table t
drop constraint the_pk;
```

If you don't want to persist it even for some time then do it inside a transaction:

```
begin;

alter table t
add constraint the_pk primary key (user_id);
```

Once satisfied roll the transaction back:

```
rollback;
```

Answer (score 1):

Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE testu ( id integer );
INSERT INTO testu SELECT generate_series(1,100);
INSERT INTO testu VALUES (1),(10),(20);
```

Demo query to find possible problem rows:

```
regress=> select id, count(id) FROM testu GROUP BY id HAVING count(id) > 1;
 id | count 
----+-------
 20 |     2
  1 |     2
 10 |     2
(3 rows)
```

Wrap it in `DO` block:

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
    PERFORM id FROM testu GROUP BY id HAVING count(id) > 1 LIMIT 1;
    IF FOUND THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'One or more duplicate IDs in table testu';
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

If you want to report the individual colliding IDs you might do that by building a string from the results of the query, by looping over the results and raising `NOTICE`s, etc. Lots of options. I'll leave that as an exercise to you, the reader, with the PL/PgSQL documentation.

Answer (score 1):

`IF EXISTS` is generally simpler and faster for this purpose in plpgsql:

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl GROUP BY tbl_id HAVING count(*) > 1) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Duplicate "tbl_id" in table "tbl"!';
    END IF;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```